# Combine multiple rows without spaces and Merging in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to generate a column that combines the values of three selected rows into a new column

```
col_1       col2      col3      col4     col5         key_column

Nivea       care       300       SSL     pre-ssl     NIVEACARE300SSL
Balea       milk       800       SSL+    pre-ssl+    BALEAMILK800SSL+
```

So, the key_column should contain values from col1,col2,col3 and col4

I am generating this column so that I can merge this data frame to another data frame where values are something like this

```
col_1       col2              col3      col4     Solution          key_column

nivea       nivea care era    300ml     SSL       1500€     NIVEANIVEACAREERA300MLSSL
balea       balea milk arc    800ml     SSL+      1540€    BALEABALEAMILKARC800MLSSL+
```

1. Can anyone help me in generating **key_column**?
2. Is there a way where I can merge these two data frames which are almost similar and has similar values at a random position? Because I have very diversed dataframe and it is difficult to change the row values comparing and looping through the data frame to perform left join to obtain the Solution column.

PS: My intention for key_column generation was to perform **fuzzy matching**. But I am worried about accuracy. Because I have to extract the price and it should be accurate.  Any other approach or suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try something like
`df['key_column'] = df['col_1]+df['col_2']+df['col3'].astype('str')`.
Remember the `.astype('str')` so the values will be all strings and they'll concatenate in the new value ( otherwise you'll get a `TypeError`.

As for the merging, I'd go for `pd.merge` but the arguments will depend on which columns you want for the new dataframe (Of course, the values in the key_columns will have to be identical).

Answer (score 0):

Probably; can use following command too for getting the key_column;

```
df1["key_column"] = df1.apply(lambda x : str(x["col1"]) + str(x["col2"]) + str(x["col3"]) + str(x["col4"]),axis=1).str.upper()
```

And also, you have the option of merging two datasets without creating the key_column (mind the lower/upper cases);

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,how="left",on=["col1","col2","col3","col4"])
```

Comment: But for merge to work the values should be the same. My data has too much randomization it is difficult to change values in rows accordingly. I am trying for an alternative approach of merge

Comment: Agreed...  As you mentioned, need to do Fuzzy or FuzzyWuzzy matching then... Best would be if you can find a pattern between two datasets & explore that... otherwise it always be a question of making some error...